# What should be dataType in ajax call for WebApi in C# returns HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, ajax, file, asp.net-web-api

WebApi Resopnse in C#

```
 public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFilesDirect(List<string> filesId)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        //code to extract file


        if (filesList == null)
        {
            return response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
        }
        else
        {
            var file = filesList[0].File;
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file.Name;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

WebApi return HttpStatusCode.OK i.e. goes into else part of code

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
             url: urlforwebapi,

             type: CONST_HTTP_POST,

             //xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },

             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

             data: JSON.stringify(data),

             success: function (result) {
                 if (callback_success != undefined) callback_success(result);
             },
             error: function () {
                 if (callback_error != undefined) callback_error();
             }
         });
```

Web Api returns Correct reponse but ajax call return to error instead of success. help me resolve issue

In ajax call -> I tried dataType with value = application/octet-stream but this is also not working.

Comment: what is `callback_success` i suspect if you solve that your problem will be gone.

Comment: @Seabizkit
even after commenting both if condition in success
 `if (callback_success != undefined) callback_success(result);`

and error
`if (callback_error != undefined) callback_error();`

Still issue is same

Comment: change `success: function (result) {...}` to `success: function (result) { debugger; }` open F12 on the browser for bugging window and inspect result. when fired

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Check the network tab and the response from the server in Debugger Tools in the Web Browser. See if the response is in compliant with your expectation

Comment: @Seabizkit i tried this but it is not entering into success. it just goes to error

@adiga @Gururaj  xhr.state() is rejected for `error: function(xhr){}`

Comment: @PratapSinghRanawat then but a debugger in fail and error to see where/what is happening, inspect the xhr and see what it says